# How to find irreducible polynomial for Barreto-Naehrig curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

As described in this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/390.pdf)(section 3) to implement pairing on Barreto-Naehrig curves. The prime in their case is $p=82434016654300679721217353503190038836571781811386228921167322412819029493183$ and to implement the pairing it is important to find an irreducible polynomial of the form $ W^6-\xi$ in $\mathbb{F}_{P^{2}}$ where $\xi \in \mathbb{F}_{P^{2}}$. However, I can not understand how to find such $\xi$. I have written some scripts in Magma to find such $\xi$ but not successful.Also in that paper they have mentioned that there are some properties of the prime $p$ which is useful in finding such $\xi$ but I can't understand how to use them? Can someone please tell me how to find such irreducible polynomials?

Comment: Select first a element $\beta \in F_p$ which is not a Quadratic Residue. By construction $X^2+\beta$ is irreducible. Then look at table 1 which give the tower construction.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI Are you sure that isn't an answer?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in $F_p$ there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic Residues and $\frac{p-1}{2}$ Non-quadratic Residues. Depending on p you can caracterize them easily. If $\beta \in QNR(p)$ then $X^2-\beta$ is irreducible in $F_p$. Then follow the construction indicated in table 1 of the article. (I've evaluated this system in 2012 for limited ressources systems such Smart Cards). And it's run. Hope it's more clear.How to select such primes. Look for criterias for which $-2 \in NQR(p)$

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Look here for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue ... if p=1, 3 mod 8 then $p \in QR(p)$ and converselly if not then ... Conclude

Comment: @RobertNACIRI I wasn't asking for a clarification :) I just had the idea that you were close to answering in the comments and I was hoping to trigger you to write an answer instead. Note that I'm not the original asker.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sur Maarteen! I'm not english native and sometimes my responses are not detailled. For me it'a a pleasure to help people. ANd I hope it's the case

Comment: I am not quite clear what you want to know, because the \xi is explicitly given in the paper. Do you want to find  irreducible elements different form \xi? Or do you want to know how the conditions to the prime p lead to the construction of \xi? Or do you want to know how to do explicit arithmetic with \xi on a computer?

Comment: @Cryptostasis I want to do explicit arithmetic on a computer. More accurately I want to compute a polynomial $W^6-\xi$ and show that the polynomial is irreducible using magma or some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

I am using  [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr) as a calculator.   In order to keep the presentation small, I will not use the $p$ you mentioned, but a toy value $p=31$, which fulfils all requirements from the paper.

First lets define p:

```
p= 31
```

Then we have to define the finite field $GF(p^2)$ via the defining (irreducible) polynomial $y^2- \beta$, i.e. $y^2+2$:

```
GFp2 = Mod (y^2+2, p)
```

Now we define $\xi$:

```
xi = -1 - y
```

( Please note that  $\sqrt \beta = y$ by the defining polynomial of $GF(p^2)$ )

Now let Pari check that $x^6- \xi$ is irreducible in $GF(p^2)$:

```
lift(factorff (x^6-xi, p, GFp2))
```

Pari responds as

```
[Mod(1, 31)*x^6 + (Mod(1, 31)*y + Mod(1, 31)) 1]
```

This says that the polynomial is irreducible.

(The "lift" call is only used to make the output more readable )

As a final test, show that $x^6 - \xi^2$ factors:

```
lift(factorff (x^6-(xi*xi), p, GFp2))
```

Pari responds as:

```
[  Mod(1, 31)*x^3 + (Mod(1, 31)*y + Mod(1, 31)) 1]

[Mod(1, 31)*x^3 + (Mod(30, 31)*y + Mod(30, 31)) 1]
```

Mathematically, this means:
$$x^6- \xi^2 = (x^3+ \sqrt \beta+1)(x^3-\sqrt\beta-1)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, if I want to check the irreducibility in the field how can I do it? I tried
> GFp6=Mod(1,GFp2)*x^3-xi, xip=x; lift(factoroff(z^2-xip)); but it does not work this way.